# Use Private variables or Properties in Constructor function

Tags: c#

```
    class Person 
{
    private string fname;
    private string lname;

    public string F 
    {
        get { return fname; }
        set { fname = value; }
    }

    public string L
    {
        get { return lname; }
        set { lname = value; }
    }

    public Person(string fname, string lname) 
    {
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
    }
}
```

Which is better, to use the properties in the constructor, or to keep it as it is above? why?

P.s.  I was using a function that uses the properties, that's why I didn't use auto properties.

Comment: What is the problem? An answer to your question depends on what you need. Both options can be fine. Anyway, auto-properties would improve readability of your code.

Comment: Its a stylistic question for the most part. I personally prefer to modify the private string and skip the property setter, just so that I don't have to worry about whether or not it will be optimized in the IL. It likely will be, though, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Actually, I was using a function that uses the properties, that's why I didn't use auto properties.

Comment: You can use auto properties from a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an immutable class do this:

```
class Person 
{
    public string F { get; private set; }
    public string L { get; private set; }

    public Person(string f, string l) 
    {
        F = f;
        L = l;
    }
}
```

For a mutable class do this:

```
class Person 
{
    public string F { get; set; }
    public string L { get; set; }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Person p = new Person { L = "laugh", F = "fun" };
```

Comment: I'd recommend adding the pubic to the class as well. However, the object initializer is one important detail that you mentioned before I did.

Comment: The public constructor is by default and doesn't need to be implemented. I agree though that it improves readability and states that you really want the default constructor. I didn't add it for keeping the code short and focussed on the question.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't going to matter, in your case I would use auto-implemented properties because you aren't performing any work in the getter or setters.

```
class Person 
{
    public string F { get; set; }

    public string L { get; set; }

    public Person(string fname, string lname) 
    {
        F = fname;
        L = lname;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use properties if callers have to modify them after constructing the
  object.
- Use get-only properties if callers have to read, but not
  change them.
- Use the constructor parameters to force callers to
  create objects that have a "good state" (eg. non-null first and last
  names)